# I have SSRS report which is generating CSV File! which was 24 million rows! it is taking too much time! because of it is giving time out Error

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS report which is generating CSV File! which was 24 million rows! it is taking too much time! because of it is giving time out Error.
how should approach this problem?

I want to create this file without timeout Error!